# i want to trim last two characters in string with selected row in selected column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

i used below query for trim function for selected rows last 2 values but that query trims the all rows last 2 characters. But i want to trim the selected rows character

```
select substr(detail,0,length(detail)-2) from address where  detail_no=1;
```

for example.

```
  row 1 text added
  row 2 last value
  row 3 end value
```

I want to trim only row 2's last 2 character any one explain how to use that query

Comment: vasanth can you please show your table defination

Comment: can u please explain with some sample data?

Comment: use row_number http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to perform an action on certain rows and not on others. Use CASE for this:

```
select 
  case when detail_no = 1 then
    then substr(detail, 1, length(detail)-2) 
  else
    detail
  end as detail
from address;
```